# java.util.InputMismatchException on easy scannerI/O demo

Tags: java, eclipse, string, exception

i can't see where the mistake is?
the eclipse gives debug current point in "System.out.println("you entered: \"" + s1 + "\"");" line but i think there is no mistake. 
could you help me? I'm new in java.

```
public class Scannerdemo {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter two whole numbers:");
    System.out.println("separated by one or more spaces:");

    int n1, n2;
    n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    n2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("you entered " + n1 +"and "+ n2);

    System.out.println("next enter two numbes.");
    System.out.println("a decimal point is OK.");

    double d1, d2;
    d1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    d2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("you entered " + d1 + "and " + d2);
    System.out.println("next enter two words:");

    String s1, s2;
    s1 = keyboard.next();
    s2 = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("you entered \"" + s1 + "\" and \"" + s2 + "\"");

    s1 = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("next enter a line of text:");
    s1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("you entered: \"" + s1 + "\"");

}
}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. Can you add the exact input you gave and produce the error?

Comment: What is the problem? If any exceptions share the stacktrace

Comment: oh... it should be my editors' mistake. i tried few more times and in the end it worked. thank you so much. but i don't understand why is it fail first time...